# How does Task.Delay work exactly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

They say Task.Delay() is an async Thread.Sleep(). To test this I wrote below code.
I expect to print immediately "One" then 3 seconds later result variable (15) will be printed. 2 seconds after this, "Two" will be printed. But it doesnt seem so. "One" is not immediately printed. "One" is printed 3 seconds later. Why does it wait 3 seconds to print "One" ?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication31
{
class Program
{
    public static int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    public static async Task DoRunAsync(int m, int n)
    {
        int result = await Task.Run(() => Multiply(m, n));
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("One");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = DoRunAsync(3, 5);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Two");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because you `await` the delay. That's the whole point of `await`: to allow you to write asynchronous code but get to treat it as synchronous where convenient. You can also store the resulting `Task` and await it later.

Comment: Why would you expect `One` to be printed immediately when it appears *after* the `Task.Delay`?

Comment: There is a difference between `synchronous` and `sequential`, await makes your code `sequential`.

Comment: Then why they call Task.Delay() is asynchronous if I should wait for the delay also? I expect the code below the delay to be executed immediately according to definition. Control returns to caller method  when it encounter await or control goes to the code below the await expression?

Comment: @Lyrk then you completely misunderstand what async is. If you `await` something you can't expect it to also be "skipped".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It takes 3 seconds to print `"One"` because you `await`-ed `Task.Delay` too soon.

Change the code as follows to get the result that you expected:

```
int result = await Task.Run(() => Multiply(m, n));
var taskDelay = Task.Delay(3000); // No blocking here, so
Console.WriteLine("One");                              // printing can proceed.
await taskDelay; // This causes a block for the remainder of 3 seconds
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

When you start the delay task prior to printing `"One"` without `await`-ing it, subsequent `WriteLine` could complete without a delay.

Comment: var taskDelay = Task.Delay(3000);                                                              
did the timer start with this statement? (I mean 3 seconds start counting with this statement? or later with "await TaskDelay" )

Comment: @Lyrk Yes, the timer starts the moment you create `taskDelay`. If you `await` the task after doing, say, two seconds worth of other work, `await` would return after one second. This is what I tried to point out in my comment inside the code.

Answer (score 12):

The job of `await` is to suspend the current method until *whatever awaitable you pass to it is complete*. How, why and *when* that awaitable was created and started are of no relevance to what the `await` keyword accomplishes.

I think you're under the impression that `await` *starts* something, when in fact it's the opposite - it marks a point in your code where you wait for something to *finish*.

Comment: thank you so much. I misunderstood wrong as you said.

Answer (score 8):

Modifying your `DoRunAsync` method as follows will make things work as intended:

```
public static async Task DoRunAsync(int m, int n)
{
    int result = await Task.Run(() => Multiply(m, n));
    Console.WriteLine("One"); // before the delay, not after...
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Your code behaves as follows:

```
await Task.Delay(3000); // Await 3 seconds...
Console.WriteLine("One"); // Once you are done awaiting, print the string...
```

If you await **before** printing the string, you can't expect it to be printed immediately...

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It seems I did not understand even the basics...